# Cannot edit /etc/hosts file in Ubuntu using Java Process.

Tags: java, linux, bash

I'm creating a Java application which accesses the hosts file(on Linux) and writes to it. I tried running the bash file which makes changes to the hosts file. Here is the code for running the bash file:

```
Process p; 
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gksudo bash Documents/file.sh");
```

Bash file has only one line:

```
echo "172.16.30.1">>/etc/hosts
```

If I run the command: "`sudo bash file.sh`" the hosts file is updated. However, using gksudo I can't.

Comment: Did you try to use `gksudo` outside of Java, starting it from a shell?

Comment: Then use `sudo` :) `gksudo` is meant to be used for graphical applications. Do you get a graphical password prompt when you run your program ?

Comment: gksudo works correctly outside of Java and also I have run processes in Java with gksudo that work fine. It is just that this particular statement does not affect the file and throws no errors, even in its error stream.

Comment: You will have to check the permissions involved. *All* permissions.

Comment: @Ploutox Yes we are working with a graphical user interface. With a prompt to enter the IP address of the machine. This address is then written to the bash file. This is working fine. But now if I have to run the bash file with 'echo "172.16.30.1">>/etc/hosts' line, I can't update it.

Comment: Have you checked your path to your file.sh ? You should change the path to "~/Documents/file.sh" unless you execute your java program from your home directory

Comment: @Shivaji_Vidhale about `gksudo`, I meant that it is used to execute graphical instructions (for instance, `gksudo gvim`). If you use terminal instructions (like `cp`, `mv`, `echo`, ...) you should use `sudo`

Comment: In order to use sudo I need to enter the sudo password which cannot be done from the Java Process. gksudo will cause a prompt to enter the sudo password when I need to execute a command with sudo priviledges.